# Python svgwrite and simultaneous animationTransforms

Tags: python, svgwrite, animatetransform

I am trying to use python svgwrite to make an object scale and rotate at the same time. My efforts has so far been to add two consecutive "animateTransform". It does however seem to only take the last action into account, as seen in my example.

```
import svgwrite 

path = [(100,100),(100,200),(200,200),(200,100)]

image = svgwrite.Drawing('test.svg',size=(300,300))

rectangle = image.add(image.polygon(path,id ='polygon',stroke="black",fill="white"))
rectangle.add(image.animateTransform("rotate","transform",id="polygon", from_="0 150 150", to="360 150 150",dur="4s",begin="0s",repeatCount="indefinite"))
rectangle.add(image.animateTransform("scale","transform",id="polygon", from_="0", to="1",dur="4s",begin="0s",repeatCount="indefinite"))

image.save()
display(SVG('test.svg'))
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This maybe comes too late, but what worked for me is adding `additive = "sum"` to both animations. Be aware that the order in which you add the animations impacts the end result.

```
import svgwrite 

path = [(100,100),(100,200),(200,200),(200,100)]

image = svgwrite.Drawing('test.svg',size=(300,300))

rectangle = image.add(image.polygon(path,id ='polygon',stroke="black",fill="white"))
rectangle.add(image.animateTransform("scale","transform",id="polygon", from_="0", to="1",dur="4s",begin="0s",repeatCount="indefinite", additive = "sum"))    
rectangle.add(image.animateTransform("rotate","transform",id="polygon", from_="0 150 150", to="360 150 150",dur="4s",begin="0s", additive = "sum", repeatCount="indefinite"))

image.save()
display(SVG('test.svg'))
```